# how to strcount each element dataframe in r

Tags: r, string, for-loop, dataframe

I have a little problem to print and count one by one array/dataframe string appearance

I have a dataframe called `Pos_1`, it contains string like these :

```
Pos_1 = (morning bliss great happy)
```

and the other dataframe called `Pos_2`, it contains string like these :

```
Pos_2 = (morning great)
```

What I want to do is, count the string that appear from `Pos_1` dataframe in `Pos_2`

I'm using the `str_count` to count each string that appear

```
for(h in 1:5)
Score=sum(str_count(Pos_2, Pos_1[h]))[1:length(Pos_1)]
```

from the code above it only return the total of all string element from `Pos_1`

```
  Text  Score 
morning  0
bliss    0 
great    0
happy    0
```

expected result from count the element that match from dataframe `Pos_1` and dataframe `Pos_2` with `strcount` (see below),

i need to produce **Only** the Score Row below

```
Text     Score
morning   1
bliss     0 
great     1 
happy     0
```

is there any solution ?

Comment: can you please add sample data

Comment: @Mr.A, hello , the sample data is written above, i want to process from dataframe Pos_1 and dataframe Pos_2

Comment: I'm still confused. Are you trying to count how many times each element of `Pos_2` appears in `Pos_1`, or are you trying, for each element of `Pos_1`, to determine if it appears in `Pos_2`?

Comment: @ulfelder , i want to count how many times each element of Pos_1 appears in Pos_2 mate, 

from example,
morning inside Pos_1, 
morning inside Pos_2,

so it return 2, 

but what i want is, how to count each element ?

Comment: @hope9, sorry, I'm still confused. In your latest comment, you first say "count how many times each element of Pos_1 appears in Pos_2", but then your example in that comment does something different.

Comment: @ulfelder my bad, sorry, i already edited the post, if i using strcount , it only count one element , i tried for loop too, but still no result

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
library(stringr)

Score <- sapply(seq_along(unlist(Pos_1)), function(i)
  sum(str_count(unlist(Pos_2), unlist(Pos_1)[i])))
```

You use `unlist` to convert your data frames of strings into vectors. Then you use `sapply` to iterate `str_count` over the elements of the unlisted `Pos_1`, getting a vector in return.

If each element of `Pos_1` will appear no more than once in `Pos_2`, you don't need `str_count` and could just use:

```
Score <- +(unlist(Pos_1) %in% unlist(Pos_2))
```

Comment: @ulferder thx a lottt , :), it worked man, awesome, I just learn this R Programming, i get the logic but lack of how to write and implement it

Comment: Glad it worked. If it did, it would be good if you would formally accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
library(stringr)

Pos_1 <- c("morning", "bliss", "great","happy")
Pos_2 <- c("morning", "great")

df<-data.frame(Text=Pos_1,Score=unlist(lapply(Pos_1,function(x) sum(str_count(x,Pos_2)))))

df
```

output

```
     Text Score
1 morning     1
2   bliss     0
3   great     1
4   happy     0
```

Comment: from the code above, i get an error, method is not aplicable